# What should I do if I can not access the Microsoft Connect Visual Studio bug report (Feedback Item) that I created?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Recently I reported a bug on Microsoft Connect (Visual Studio and .NET Framework section). After some time I've received a mail with a request that I create a small demo application which would reproduce the bug.

I've made the application and then I wanted to attach it to the feedback item. The email contained the link to the feedback item (it's a public bug so I guess it is OK to put the link here): http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1762726/changing-the-namespace-of-a-class-which-is-decorated-with-collectiondatacontract-silently-fails-deserialization).

Unfortunately once I navigated to that page I got 'Page Not Found' (the actual message:
*Page Not Found

The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it.*

Thankfully inside the same email there is this section:
*If you are having trouble accessing the Feedback link above, please go to the http://connect.microsoft.com/help/default.aspx page to report the issue,  In your submission, please make sure to paste a copy the link above into the report.*

Unfortunately (again) when I go to this page I get a weird page which does not look like a regular page but rather like a part of a frameset (notice the small 'back' button which is active but actually does not do anything):
[image: https://connect.microsoft.com/help/default.aspx]

I am now at a loss on what to do next. Should I re-report the bug or something like that? Normally I would complain to Microsoft about this but I have no idea how to report a problem with their problem reporting?!?

Comment: That link works for me (Windows 10 Edge) - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1762726/changing-the-namespace-of-a-class-which-is-decorated-with-collectiondatacontract-silently-fails-deserialization.  Suggest you try IE and or Clear Cookies.

Comment: The link (the original one) now works for me (try clicking on it).
I do not know why it would not work before. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The link seems to work now, I guess that the Microsoft Connect site had some issues before.